# How do I correct this statement?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have received this statement in an assignment, and was told to correct the error. I don't know what the goal of the statement is exactly, could someone perhaps explain this? Thanks.

```
double a[1][2] = {{2,3}, {3,2}};
```

Comment: How large is the array?  How many initializers are provided?  What error do you get if you try to compile it?

Comment: @BenVoigt this is the only statement given. Nothing else is given at all. The error is      error: too many initializers for ‘double [1][2]’

Comment: All three of those questions were about this line of code.  They are meant to lead you to understand it yourself, which you will not understand if I simply tell you what change to make.

Comment: It seems more context is required. Choices are: 1. Allocate more element to match the initializer. 2. Reduce number of elements in the initializer to match the array dimension. 3. Remove the entire statement.

Comment: @MikeCAT: #1 is the only reasonable approach.  One must assume that the initializer data is meaningful or else it wouldn't be there.

Comment: Just change 1 for 2: `double a[2][2] = {{2,3}, {3,2}};`.

Comment: `{{2,3}, {3,2}};` is an initialization for a 2x2 array. You have `a[1][2]` (1-row, 2-cols). So as @Daniel says above, make your declaration match the initializer or vice-versa, up to you.

Comment: @Daniel so which value is put into which location? Is it row 1: 2,3  row 2: 3,2?

Comment: Declaring an plain-old 2D array is `type name[rows][cols]`. The initializer is `{ {row1, col1}, {row2, col2} }`. So it is up to you what value you put where, but you must make `rows` and `cols` from the declaration match what is in the initializer. Your initializer does not have to contain a value for every row/col. Any element not explicitly initialized will be initialized to zero by default so long as at least one element is initialized. Otherwise, if no initializer is used, no elements are initialized and all values are left indeterminate.

Comment: But also remember array indexes are Zero based in C, so for a 2x2 2D array, the valid indexes are `0,0` (first row first element) `0,1` (first row second element), `1,0` (second row first element) and so on...

Comment: @BenVoigt -- one must not assume anything; the problem statement is ambiguous. In the real world, this kind of thing could come from modifying the code, with the intention of having a smaller array. The only correct answer is "ask the person who wrote it".

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: `{ {row1, col1}, {row2, col2} }`  Uh, no.  It's `{ { row0col0, row0col1 }, { row1col0, row1col1 } }`

Comment: @BenVoigt - absolutely right you are, I knew what I was thinking, but there was some caffeine deficient disconnect between the brain and keyboard -- thank you.

Comment: It is done as `2f,d%`.

Answer (score 3):

You want

```
double a[][2] = {{2, 3}, {3, 2}};
```

C++ allows you to omit the bounds of the first dimension, but no other. `double a[2][2]` is an alternative, but is superfluous. The way I've written it is extensible in the sense that

```
double a[][2] = {{2, 3}, {3, 2}, {0, 0}};
```

will create a multi-dimensional array with the the bound of the first dimension set to 3.

Answer (score 0):

> *I don't know what the goal of the statement is exactly, could someone perhaps explain this?*

At risk of being redundant, the goal of the statement is to declare a two dimensional array and initialize it with some values.

The error you mention:

> *error: too many initializers for 'double [1][2]'*`

Is quite self explanatory I think, there are too many values in the initializer list, you need to try and understand how many values the array can take, and how many values are being assigned, and from there draw your conclusions and correct the code accordingly.

To be more clear, you surely know that the first dimension of a 2D array is usually represented as being the number of rows, and the second as being the number of colums, so the question is, how many elements can an array with 1 line and 2 columns take? Or if you prefer, how many elements can a `2 X 1` 2D array take, and what a about a `5 X 5` one?

Answer (score 0):

Both @Bathsheba and @David C. Rankin are correct in their comments, so I'll just re-sum what's been said, and hopefully it makes some sense, but in a different way. It's not the most obvious error when you look at it plain-faced.

You have the line `double a[1][2] = {{2,3}, {3,2}};`, for which you were asked to find and solve an error in the code. Your error statement was "too many initializers for `double[a][b]`". If you deconstruct the line of code, it begins to make more sense.

`double a[1][2]` is your **declaration** of a two-dimensional array that is 1x2. Visually, you can imagine that what is being created from the current line looks like this:

```
// 1x2; I could be wrong about the order in which the numbers are assigned, so grain of salt here:
╔═════╗
║  2  ║ // holds the 2 from {2, 3}
╠═════╣
║  3  ║ // holds the 3 from {3, 2}
╚═════╝
```

Each box, or cell, or unit of that array can only store one value at any given moment.

Now let's look at the **assignment:** `= { {2,3}, {3,2} };`

Each of those lists hold two values, for a total of four. Do you see the error now? That line of code is trying to place too many values into too small of a **container** (which is what an array is, just something that holds data, regardless of the number of dimensions). So if your goal is to store all four values, then visually, you can imagine that it looks something like this:

```
// 2x2; again, grain of salt
╔═════╦═════╗
║  2  ║  3  ║ // {2, 3}
╠═════╬═════╣
║  3  ║  2  ║ // {3, 2}
╚═════╩═════╝
```

And this can be accomplished in at least few ways, first, as suggested by @David C. Rankin, make the declaration match the assignment,

i.e. change `double a[1][2] = { {2, 3}, {3, 2} };`

to `double a[2][2] = { {2, 3}, {3, 2} };`

or second, as suggested by @Bathsheba, change the declaration such that it automatically detects the dimension of what you're trying to assign, i.e. the form `double a[][2]` where, as mentioned, it could not be the other way around, like `double a[2][]`.